# Change the size of AssetGroupId EDT

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a request to change size of `GroupId` field in `AssetGroup` table from 10 to 18.

As far as i see, this field extends `AssetGroupId` EDT which in turn extends `SysGroup` ( and this way it takes the size of 10 ).

Is it the correct approach to stop extending `SysGroup` on `AssetGroupId` EDT and change the `StringSize` property to 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a possible approach, but it introduces update conflicts for the `AssetGroupId` EDT. Be also aware that with this approach you will to check all references for the EDT and all table fields that use the EDT if they need to be modified to fit the new EDT size.

Is there a reason why the `Name` field of table `AssetGroup` cannot be used to provide further information?

Comment: Name it is then. There are a lot of references to that EDT indeed. It's too dangerous to check them all and be sure I covered each possible shrinking operation. Thanks!

Comment: It's also a performance consideration. The group is an identifier, so an index to construct, to update, to look into, and so on...